# Why does Eclipse's expression view fail on some classes?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, java

For a research project, I'm developing on the OpenJDK sources with Eclipse. For debugging purposes, the "Expressions" and the "Display" views of the integrated debugger are quite helpful. When stepping through the code of the `javac` compiler tool, the expressions view fails on *some* classes. Then, even the simplest expressions get an `<error(s)_during_the_evaluation>` in their value column. 
The detailed error message is then:

```
Evaluations must contain either an expression or a block of well-formed statements
```

I'm pretty sure, I have entered valid expressions, as a simple switch to the calling method (one stack frame higher) makes the view working.

I've uploaded two screenshots two make the problem clearer:

**Not-working class `JavacParser`:**
[image: Not-working class]

**Working class `EndPosParser`:**
[image: Working class]

Has anybody ever experienced a similar problem or knows what the reason is or how to fix it? When switching between the two shown views, I don't do anything else than going one stack frame higher. Both expressions are expected to be evaluated in both cases. As far as I can evaluate it, the shown failing behavior only occurs in the `JavacParser` class.

Thanks!

Comment: I bumped into so many old reports and bug fixes for this error specifically but they all seem to be related to older problems (i.e.: classes with generics, with versions 3.1-3.8), I'm now on 4.x+ and still seeing this. Hopefully someone will find an explanation so it can be reported.

Comment: I've managed to get around that by overriding the toString() method. Might want to give that a shot. Quite a hack-y way of achieving this though. I'll update this later if I come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, expressions are evaluated in the context of the current (topmost) stackframe.

It seems like your first screenshot was taken when a object (`EndPosParser`) was constructed. As your object does not exist yet, `this` can not be evaluated. The reference to `this` can not be evaluated until the super-call chain reached `Object`.

I'm not sure why `1+2` can not be evaluated. My best guess would be:
Eclipse recognizes constructors as non-static method and tries to evaluate `1+2` in a non-static context. But this fails again, because `this` does not exists yet.

*Edit: That's a damn old question I just tried to answer...*